# Add a option to migrate SO

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons, migration

I found a lot of question that belongs on SO, But i didn't found a option to migrate SO but CGCC Meta.

I want a option to migrate SO.

Answer (score 6):

**I do not support having a migration path for this.**

Very rarely are questions here actually suitable for migration.

Just close them with the existing off-topic option. If you believe they should be migrated, you can flag them for moderator attention or ping a moderator in chat referencing the bot post, but before you do so, think carefully, because it's probably not actually good for migration.

In my past over a year as a moderator, a grand total of zero posts have been successfully migrated onto Stack Overflow. I do not want to allow normal users to migrate to SO because there are a lot of things that look migrateable but actually are not, and it is better to just tell the user to repost there and read through the help center.

Migration does have its uses, just not often applicable here.

Comment: And often users come here having been banned from SO